# Signals Behavior in C/C++ - Linux

Tags: c, unix, signals

Completely new to processes and signals and I was messing around with the following code I wrote :

```
void childSignalHandler(int signalCode) {

    if (signalCode == SIGUSR1)
        cout << "Child here : Received ping, responding" << endl;
}

void parentSignalHandler(int signalCode) {

    if (signalCode == SIGINT)
        cout << "Parent here : Pinging Child" << endl;

    else if (signalCode == SIGUSR1)
        cout << "Parent here : Received response" << endl;

}


int main() {

    int pid = fork();

    /* Child process*/
    if (pid == 0) {

        if (signal(SIGUSR1, childSignalHandler) == SIG_ERR) {
            perror("Child SIGUSR1");
            exit(1);
        }
        // This did the trick!
        if (signal(SIGINT,SIG_IGN) == SIG_ERR){
            perror("Child SIGINT");
            exit(1);
        }

        pause();
        kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
    } else {

        if (signal(SIGINT, parentSignalHandler) == SIG_ERR) {
            perror("Parent SIGINT");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (signal(SIGUSR1, parentSignalHandler) == SIG_ERR) {
            perror("Parent SIGUSR1");
            exit(1);
        }
        raise(SIGINT); // Maybe change it to pause(); to use keyboard instead ?
        kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
        pause();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The code above works perfectly fine and the expected behavior is :

```
Parent here : Pinging Child
Child here : Received ping, responding
Parent here : Received response
```

However when I tried the same thing using the keyboard `Ctrl + C` signal and changed the `raise(SIGINT);` to `pause();` then the output was :

```
^CParent here : Pinging Child
^CParent here : Pinging Child
```

The way I thought this would work is :

- Both processes will be paused
- `CTRL + C` aka `SIGINT` will be sent to the parent process which will be *unpaused*
- `parentSignalHandler()` will handle `SIGINT` and the appropriate message will be printed
- Parent process will send a `SIGUSR1` to the child process which will be unpaused and the parent process itself will be paused again
- `childSignalHandler()` will handle `SIGUSR1`
- Finally the child process will send a `SIGUSR1` to the parent process,which once again will be handled by `parentSignalHandler()`

As it seems it does not work the way I imagined and any insight would be really helpful.

**Edit -- Updated Code**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raise(SIGINT)` sends `SIGINT` signal only to the calling process - which is the parent process in this case. On the other hand, when you send the `SIGINT` signal using `CTRL + C` you send it to *all of the foreground processes*, i.e. the child process also receives it and therefore terminates. So there's no more a child process to reply to the `SIGUSR1` signal of the parent process. Try ignoring the signal in the child process.